# Error 596 when trying to connect to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2016 that runs locally on my machine. The connection used to work well until today. I'm getting an error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to ***.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 596).

I checked in `services.msc` that the SQL Server service is running. Any ideas what may cause the issue?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree [flag to move](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) - *Flag >> Should be closed... >> Off topic because... >> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? Have you tried to use DAC to see what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

As it turned out the issue occured because some of sql files got corrupted. The fix for the issue was repairing Sql Server using it's installer.